# How to make loadingscreen in center in kony

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am developing desktop application using kony framework. while login my loader is not appearing in center. its just loading in right side. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your loading screen by following :

`kony.application.showLoadingScreen(skin, text, position, isBlocked, showProgressIndicator, properties)`

where the `position` is given as `constants.LOADING_SCREEN_POSITION_ONLY_CENTER` which will display the loading screen only at the center. By default it would be full screen `constants.LOADING_SCREEN_POSITION_FULL_SCREEN`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to show **loadingscreen in center**:

```
function showLoadingScreen(){
  kony.application.showLoadingScreen(null, "Please wait...", 
  constants.LOADING_SCREEN_POSITION_ONLY_CENTER, true, true, {  
  shouldShowLabelInBottom: "true", separatorHeight: 30} )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 kony.application.showLoadingScreen("", "", constants.LOADING_SCREEN_POSITION_ONLY_CENTER, true, true, null);
```